# CodeAcademy; program not working in JS

Tags: javascript

So code academy says I completed this correctly yet it doesn't yield any result.  It is supposed to fine how many times the name "Alex" appears in the var text.  Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong?

Note: the result from this current code is just = []

Thank you in advance, here is the code:

```
var text = "Alex, blah, Alex, blah, blah, blah, Alex, blah, Alex"

var myName = "Alex"
var hits = []

for (var i=0; i<text.length; i++){
    if (text[i] === "A"){
        for (var j = i; j < i + myName.length;j++){
            hits.push(j);
        }
    }
}

if (hits.length = 0){
    console.log("Your name wasn't found")
}
else{
    console.log(hits);
}
```

Comment: CodeAcademy is pretty obviously incorrect.  To start, change your hits length test from `hits.length = 0` (assigning a length) to `hits.length == 0` (testing the length).  Your IDE would normally warn you about this sort of thing, since there's tons of compilers that don't you may want to conder using "Yoda conditions" to avoid this sort of error (i.e. `if (0 == hits.length)`

Comment: Also related to what Tibrogargan said (as a side note) using `array.length = 0` will delete all of the contents of that array.

Comment: Thank you for both identifying the == error + informing me about editing my posts :)

Comment: @Alex There's other issues.  Your code will match Alex, sure ... but it will also match Alice, Albert, Advocado and YAAAA! (The last one 4 times)

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to use regular expressions, this is pretty simple...

```js
var text = "Alex, blah, Alex, blah, blah, blah, Alex, blah, Alex"

var myName = "Alex"
var hits = []

hits = text.match(new RegExp( "\\b"+myName+"\\b", "g"));

if (hits.length == 0){
    console.log("Your name wasn't found")
}
else{
    console.log(hits);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem here:

```
hits.push(j); // you push index not symbol
```

Should be:

```
 hits.push(text[j]);
```

And my solution:

```
var text = "af grwg rh thrthj jjy jtj Denys g er Denys";
var myName = "Denys";
var hits = [];
var k = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
    if (text[i] === "D"){
        for(var j = i; j < myName.length + i; j++){
            hits.push(text[j]);
        }
        ++k;
    }    
}
if (hits === []){
    console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
}
else{
    console.log("Your name was found " + k + " times!");
}
```

Also I  want ask you: do you know about https://discuss.codecademy.com ?

I think you can find answer faster there. But it is your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, there's a neat Array method called "reduce" that takes an array and returns a single value. You can turn your text into an array with String's split method.

```js
var text = "Alex, blah, Alex, blah, blah, blah, Alex, blah, Alex";
var textArray = text.split(', ');    // split into an array
var myName = "Alex";

// reduce the array to a single value.
// Just increase a counter each time the name matches.

var total = textArray.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  if (curr === myName) ++prev;
  return prev;
}, 0);
console.log(total);

// or if you want to get small.
// "Variables? Variables? We don't need no stinking' variables!"

console.log("Alex, blah, Alex, blah, blah, blah, Alex, blah, Alex".split(', ').reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return curr === "Alex" ? ++prev : prev;
}, 0));
```